# Reaching maximum number of solver variables?

Tags: vba, excel, solver

I'm using excel solver for an optimization problem (maximization using the evolutionary/genetic algorithm). Yet, I didn't had any problems after setting bottom and top boundaries for perhaps 3-4 input variables and about 1,000 samples. The fitness function is quite simple, just the sum of all outputs called. Is I used to have a (1000 x 4) input matrix and a corresponding (1000 x 1) output column vector.

Now, I have 42 input variables ([which is less than the maximum size of variables solver should handle](https://www.solver.com/standard-excel-solver-dealing-problem-size-limits)). Unfortunately, the GA doesn't find a optimal solution (it filters out all outputs; so i get just #NA called from my column vector). I know from 'trying-out' that changing just one variable improves model fitness. So Solver/GA seems to have problems running the 'hill climbing'.

Empirically, I figured out that 14 variables set as bottom threshold) or 5+5 variables set as bottom + top threshold are the maximum Solver can deal with.
Settings are pretty standard and I checked different modifications.

Constraint Precision: 0.001 - 0.000001
Scaling: On / Off

Convergence (GA): 0.001 - 0.000001
Population Size: 0, 100, 200
Mutation Rate: 0.01, 0.075, 0.2, 0.5, 0.9

After ~40 iterations it stops and no outputs has been called (100% filtered out).

Has someone else experienced this issue? Did I reached the limits of Excel solver or the GA? If yes, is there a solution solving my problem in Excel or do I have to Matlab/Python library, which can deal with so many variables?

Comment: I think if you hit the variable limit you get a message like "too many adjustable cells" and the algorithm would not even start. I suspect something else is going like (like the evolutionary algorithm generating points that cannot be evaluated). You could try the GRG nonlinear solver instead.

Answer (score 1):

Excel solver has a limit of 200 variable cells. If you hit any more than 200 adjustable cells, you will see this message.

You have 2 options:

- Reduce the number of adjustable cells, by manipulating your problem.
- Try other solvers available other than excel, having higher limits of adjustable cells.